# Convert String in 24 Hour time to 12 Hour AM PM Time

Tags: java, datetime

Returned the exact String for "closing time" below from my json Result. It appears to be in 24hour time format. I did a little search around and noticed it is not in the desired format of HH:MM:SS. What's an efficient way to convert this to a 12Hour AM PM time. Thanks.`

```
String closingTime = "2100";
//Desired output: String closingTime = "9:00 pm"
```

Comment: So what's the desired output for `"2100"`?

Comment: Desired output is 9 pm. Thanks

Comment: So what do you mean by `the desired format of HH:MM:SS`? And 2100 is 9 PM.

Comment: corrected to 9pm. it was a typo. That should be military time I suppose. Most solutions I found showed conversions from that format to 12Hour time format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest parsing the time into a Calendar object. This makes it very easy to actually do stuff with the time given, rather than just dealing with it as a string

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

//Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY is in 24-hour format
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, closingTime.substring(0,2));

time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, closingTime.substring(2,4));

//Calendar.HOUR is in 12-hour format
System.out.print(time.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + time.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
```

The above code will print out "9:00 PM" if you give it "2100", but the data internally is stored as millis so you can do so much more with it if you need.

**EDIT**
The above code was not correct, more like pseudocode, as noted by the asker, who suggested the following, much more complete, working code:

```
String closingTime = "2101";
//getInstance() will return the current millis, so changes will be made relative to the current day and time
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
// Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY is in 24-hour format
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(closingTime.substring(0, 2)));

// time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) returns the exact minute integer e.g for 10:04 will show 10:4
// For display purposes only We could just return the last two substring or format Calender.MINUTE as shown below
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(closingTime.substring(2, 4)));
String minute = String.format("%02d", time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

// time.get(Calendar.AM_PM) returns integer 0 or 1 so let's set the right String value
String AM_PM = time.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 ? "AM" : "PM";

// Calendar.HOUR is in 12-hour format
System.out.print("...\n" + time.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + minute + " " + AM_PM);
```

Comment: The accepted answer works fine as well but your method is the most useful since the time is being converted to a Calendar object. I have some additions to add. I'll edit right below your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Date getDateFromString(String format, String dateStr) {

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }
```

/////////////////////

```
public static String getCurrentDate(String format) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfFrom = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        return (sdfFrom.format(currentTime.getTime()));
    }
```